# Show that $1*1=\tau$, $I*I=I \times \tau$, $1*I=\sigma$, $\mu * \tau=1$, and $\mu * \sigma=I$

Tags: number-theory

Show that $1*1=\tau$, $I*I=I \times \tau$, $1*I=\sigma$, $\mu * \tau=1$, and $\mu * \sigma=I$.

I am not familiar with the use of these symbols. This functions are all multiplicative arithmetic functions. Can someone explain how to do at least one of them, preferably one of the more difficult one?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what $1$, $\tau$, $\sigma$, $\mu$ and $I$ represent? Further what do $*$ and $\times$ represent for that matter?

Comment: I'd guess one of these is convolution product on Dirichlet series... I'd like from the OP definitions of $*$ versus $\times$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Refer to page 15-16 of this document for the definition

Comment: @UsernameUnknown what document?

Comment: There is a special hyperlinking mode where only 50k+ users can see them on stackexchange. If you read the fine-print of the html you can see it. OP must have been inducted into the secret society.

Answer (score 1):

These arithmetic functions are

$$1(n):=1, \quad I(n):=n,\quad \tau(n):=\sum_{d\mid n}1,\quad \sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d.$$

The binary operations $*$ and $\times$ on arithmetic functions are Dirichlet convolution (which is given explicitly by $(f*g)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)$) and pointwise multiplication respectively.

The relations $\tau=1*1$ and $\sigma=1*I$ should be pretty obvious. As $1$ and $I$ are both multiplicative functions, and the convolutions of two multiplicative functions is multiplicative (check this!), the functions $\tau$ and $\sigma$ must also be multiplictive. So to check $I*I=I\times\tau$ and $\mu*\sigma=I$, it will suffice to check that these equalities are true for all prime-power arguments $p^e$, and the divisors of the number $n=p^e$ are easy to describe: they are $\{1,p,p^2,\cdots,p^e\}$.

Comment: Can you should $I*I=I \times \tau$?

Comment: $I*I=(I*I)(n)=\sum_{d|n}I(n)I(n)=\sum_{d|n}n^2$ and I am stuck there

Comment: @Username $(I*I)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}I(d)I(n/d)$.